# Get text from a <p> with specific id in Android using Jsoup

Tags: android, webview, jsoup

I want to fetch some data from my website using Jsoup in my webview. The website is still in development so I can't post any code but here's what I want to achieve:

So the user visits the website where all data I require in the app is loaded onto one page. So I want to fetch all that data as separate strings and use them to fill my table layout. The website has all that I want with each string in a p tag with a unique id.

How can I achieve this? I already have jsoup installed but I can't get my head around how to use it.

Comment: please show us the html code  you want extract the text from

Comment: @JavaFan the html code is not ready yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if you want to extract element that has id so use    `select(element_name#id_name)`

To extract text that element involves it use `.text()`

Again  show us the html part you want to extract the text from

So try this code

```
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("your url").get();
    System.out.println(doc.select("p#id_name").text());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thanks man ill try it out.Actually I have high hopes on this one.Was trying something like that too but just didnt know how to set it right